# Render validation error messages on the page for partial forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a bug show/edit form, which contains partials to add comments and attachment.

When a user tries to submit invalid attachment type or an empty comment, the validation would throw an error `[validates :comment, presence: true]` and similar for attachment[`using paperclip gem`], now when this happens, I want the error messages to be displayed on the same bug form.

The repo is at @ [GitHub Link](https://github.com/hsdqa/bugtracker)

In my show form I have

```
show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'bug_attachments/bug_form' %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>

comments/form.html.erb
<% @comment = Comment.new %>
<%= form_for [@bug, @comment] do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a comment" %>
<%= f.submit 'Add Comment'%>
<% end %>


comments_controller.rb
class Bugs::CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_bug

def create
  @comment = @bug.comments.new comment_params
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to bug_path(@comment.bug_id), notice: 'Comment added successfully'
  else
    # Here I am setting @bug = 1 since when the user posts the comments, the @bug becomes nil.
    @bug = Bug.find(1)
    render 'bugs/show'
    # redirect_to @comment, alert: 'Unable to save your comment'
  end
 end
 private
  def set_bug
   @bug = Bug.find(params[:bug_id])
  end
  def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
 end
end
```

Any help here please?

Comment: you achieve this by adding ajax to your form. `remote: true`

Comment: @Marv-C - can you pls tell how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so (edited for your project):

```
<% if @comment && @comment.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
    <li><%= error_message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Another interesting way to do it is in a flash:

*On your controller:*

```
if @comment.errors.any?
  flash[:error] = @comment.full_messages.join(', ')
  redirect_to #somewhere
else
```

Comment: thanks, the `flash[:errors]` thing works fine. about the `@comment.errorys.any` I had given a try but while doing this @comment becomes nil and does not render the error messages, not sure why? my understanding is with redirect the previous errors do not persist with redirect and is a fresh request.

Comment: Did you specify validations in your model?

Comment: Yes have specified the validations in model

Comment: Got it to work, I didn't dwelve much into your code but that's it. I have edited my answer, please upvote it if it helps.